# javascript/firebug skipping lines of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, firebug

Here's part of my code:

```
1  if (document.forms[0]["displayAddress"].value == "true") {
2    if (document.forms[0]["addressPresent"].value == "") {
3      $("#addressDiv").show();
4      document.forms[0]["addressPresent"].value = "true";
5    }
6  }
```

Why would firebug skip over line 3? - in dubug mode it doesnt even highlight that row, just skips to the next.

edit: to clarify, line 2 evaluates to true and the debugger goes straight to line 4 without executing line 3. I have tried a forced refresh.

update: the first time the page loads this JS works, after the page is reloaded again I get this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the condition

```
(document.forms[0]["addressPresent"].value == "")
```

evaluates to true?

If it does and  it just jumps to line 4, have you evaluated that it is actually executing line 3?  It could be that the debugger in Firebug is skipping it.  Have you tried to break on that line?

Try breaking on that line.

Comment: Sorry I should have explained better. yes the expression evalutes to true, and the debugger skips over line 3 (doesnt highlight) and goes straight to 4 after the if on line 2. Yesline 4 executes and line3 doesnt

Answer (score 1):

I've had Firebug act a little wonky with me at times. Usually a complete closing of Firefox and Firebug will fix the problem. If you need a second opinion, try Chrome's debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on this in the end and re-wrote the whole method. It now works. Something strange was going on.